# ¿Cómo comparar palabras sin considerar mayúsculas, minúsculas y acentos?

Tags: php, php7

Necesito buscar palabras en cadenas o textos con `PHP`, actualmente estoy usando la función `stripos()` pero el problema se presenta cuando hay acentos ya que no encuentra la coincidencia, por el momento tengo esto:

```
$pos = stripos($texto, $buscar);
if ($pos !== false) {                           
    echo "Encontrado!";
}
```

¿Cómo podría buscar palabras siendo insensible a mayúsculas, minúsculas y acentos? Gracias.

Comment: Añade por favor lo que hayas intentado

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz Listo!

Comment: que tal si antes de comparar llevas la cadena de texto y comparas `$pos = stripos(strtoupper($texto), strtoupper($buscar));`

Comment: He probado el codigo pero no funciona, cuando la palabra tiene acento la deja en minuscula y aun con el acento.

Answer (score 3):

Primero debes normalizar el texto en que se hace la búsqueda y el texto a buscar a uno que no tenga caracteres extraños, para eso puedes usar una función similar a `normalizarTexto`

```
function normalizarTexto($input) {
  $input = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);
  $input = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $input);
  $input = strtolower($input);
  // echo $input;
  return $input;
}
```

1. La primera linea quita tildes, diéresis, etc. Convirtiendo `á` en `a` o `ñ` en `n`.

`$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);`

2. Todo caracter distinto a [a-z,A-Z,0-9] sera reemplazado por un _

`$input = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $input);`

3. Convertimos a minusculas el texto `$input = strtolower($input);`

**Ahora normalizamos el texto y hacemos la búsqueda:**

```
$pos = stripos(normalizarTexto($texto), normalizarTexto($buscar));
if ($pos !== false) {
  echo "Encontrado!";
}
```

Si el `$texto` es muy largo el script sera lento, no es recomendable usar esto en textos grandes con php, para eso existen otros métodos mas óptimos.

Comment: y que pasa con las ñ y acentos?

Comment: Te a comentado que las ñ pasa a ser n

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, he probado el codigo pero no me funciona porque me remplaza los acentos por guiones bajos y esto la sigue volviendo imposible de comparar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la solucion sería añadir el   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');

```
    function normalizarTexto($input) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
  $input = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);
  $input = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $input);
  $input = strtolower($input);
  return $input;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué "crees"? ¿Probastes la solución? ¿Puedes explicarla?